# Extract nth tags from HTML after specific tag with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parser

Using beautifulsoup, I have some HTML var like this :

```
<head>....<\head>
<body>
<h2> my title <\h2>
<p> text text text <\p>
<p> text2 text2 <\p>

<h2> my title 2<\h2>
<p> text text text <\p>
```

I want to extract every  and the next

tags.

Example i wat to get  :

First = " my title <\h2>

text text text <\p>

text2 text2 <\p>"

Second = " my title <\h2>

text text text <\p>"

Knowing that in each document, the number of  and

tags is varibal.

Can anyone suggest an approach or a way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

How about doing like this

let page =

```
<head>....<\head>
<body>
<h2> my title <\h2>
<p> text text text <\p>
<p> text2 text2 <\p>

<h2> my title <\h2>
<p> text text text <\p>
```

and

```
parser = '<h2> my title <\h2>'
a = parser + page.split(parser)
b = parser + page.split(parser)
```

Comment: Thank you but its variabl number of <h2> there are documents with 5 others with 6 titles also <p> is variable ...

Comment: parser = '<h2>'
length = page.split(parser)
for i in range(length)
    a = parser + page.split(parser)[i+1]